# How does milliondollarhomepage work?

Tags: asp.net

I noticed the pixel array is only one image, I wonder if it is dynamically created on a page request and then cached? Is that possible to do with .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't be supprised if the entire page was completely static. It looks like nothing more than an image with an Area Map over the top of it, the query string just changes the image from the previous cached one, probably incremented when he was selling pixels.

http://milliondollarhomepage.com/img-pix/image-map.png?r=476

There's no reason why you can't dynamically generate the image server-side and cache it. So yes it's possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes I suppose he has probably rewritten the script now that its finished and it just a screencapture of the finalised pixel array. 

In terms of how this used to work dynamically, how do you think? I think images were probably stored in the database as BLOBS or something, the entire image was then created by the aggregation of this pixel data, do you think this is plausible? The best way to do this? Very interesting :)! I suppose it comes down to whether it would be quicker to process 1000 images and convert, or grab 1000 rows from the DB..?

Comment: I think when he originally created the website back in 2005, because he was studying Business rather than something IT related, he most likely didn't have the technical ability to manage the layout of image's in PHP (not saying he didn't know PHP, just that it might have been too advanced at that point in time). It was probably just static HTML when he began. Even how I see no reason for it to be anything other than static because it never changes.

Comment: If you want to create something similar then it is possible to create a system where people pick an area, upload an image, and you can store that image and where it belongs, and use that to dynamically create a new image that is then used to display on your web page. Which would be good for having images change. But the development would take a while. (in my opinion)

Comment: Yes! This is what I am thinking as well, I think it would be possible Thanks Phill :-)!

Answer (score 1):

It's a single giant image with an [image map](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)

You can see this by viewing the source.

Also, being that the image has a querystring parameter, I'm assuming that the image generation and map generation is all being done server side.

```
src="img-pix/image-map.png?r=323"
```

And "YES" this is possible to do entirely in .NET

Comment: I think that query string might just be there for cache purposes? I'm not too sure, thanks for your answer!

Comment: Well I know that if I were building it, I'd hate to manually map that image. I'd definitely do it server side.